# Quantikz draw strike on double wire and arrow on vertical wires

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I'm trying to draw [this circuit](https://quantumcomputinguk.org/tutorials/introduction-to-the-swap-test-in-qiskit-with-code) using [`quantikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz). I don't know how to draw the strike symbol on the double wire, or the down arrow from the `\meter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$q_0$} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \gate{H} & \meter{} & \qw \\
\lstick{$q_1$} & \qw & \targX{} & \qw & \qw \vcw{-1} & \qw & \\
\lstick{$q_2$} & \qw & \targX{} & \qw & \qw \vcw{-1} & \qw \\
\lstick{$c$} & \cw\qwbundle[nwires=2]{1} & \cw & \cw & \cw \vcw{-1} & \cw{} \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close. Added two commands: to draw the double arrow and to make the strike over the double lines.

Notice the use of `\swap{1}` instead of `\targX{}` in the second row.

[image: f]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\tikzset{
    operator/.append style={fill=blue!20,  color=blue!20},
}

\newcommand{\vcwdouble}[3]{
    \arrow[from=#1,to=#2,arrows, Rightarrow, double distance=.2mm, line width=.2mm, ->, shorten >=1pt, >=latex, "#3" {anchor=south west, yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt},  at end ] 
}
    
\newcommand{\qwbundledouble}[1]{
            \arrow[phantom,strike arrow]{l}[xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/quantikz/Strike Width}, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/quantikz/Strike Height},anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-2pt]{\scriptstyle #1}\cw
    }
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{$q_0$} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \gate{H} & \meter{}\vcwdouble{1-5}{4-5}{0} & \qw \\
        \lstick{$q_1$} & \qw & \swap{1} & \qw & \qw  & \qw & \\
        \lstick{$q_2$} & \qw & \targX{} & \qw & \qw  & \qw \\
        \lstick{$c$}    &\qwbundledouble{1} & \cw & \cw & \cw  &\cw{} \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

**Option** a single line arrow (it looks better). Try

```
\newcommand{\vcwsingle}[3]{
    \arrow[from=#1,to=#2,arrows,  ->, shorten >=1pt, >=latex, "#3" {anchor=south west, yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt},  at end ] 
}
```